# Problems get NTLM working with Apache / Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, single-sign-on, ntlm

my boss wants me to use SSO for your new intranet webpage (PHP/Symfony2), but i've got a problem to get NTLM running :(

I am working on OpenSUSE 11.4, using Apache/2.2.17.
Module auth_ntlm_winbind_module (shared) is loaded and winbind is working too (wbinfo -g shows me all users). The NTLM Stuff is configured in the .htaccess file:

```
AuthType NTLM
NTLMAuth on
AuthName "Authentication"
NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 /login
ErrorDocument 500 /login
```

So, in my opinion, everything is fine...
When requesting the webpage in Firefox (yeah, network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris is configured to the url :)), two requests are made and i get two responses:

Request #1:

```
GET /ticket/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ts.dev-fabian
```

Response #1:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

This is normal (according to google :)) and so automatically Request 2 is fired up:

Request #2:

```
GET /ticket/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ts.dev-fabian
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAA[...]AAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
```

Response #2:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

Either the Authorization in Req.#2 is not correct (how can i verify this?) or the authentication on server side fails, i always get a 500 Internal Server Error :(

Any Ideas what I am (or the server is) doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Fabian